# HW-accelerated MP3 decoding in Windows Mobile-s

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, mp3

I have found some native C# libraries decoding MP3-s. I tried one and it did work fine on PC. But when I deployed it on my relatively new and powerful WinMo phone, it could not decode the mp3 files with the speed required for playing them. It was starving on CPU.

I expect that most of our recent phones contain HW accelerated MP3 decoding. Let me know if I am daydreaming. But if not, how can I utilize that feature on a Windows Mobile programatically?

If solutions are device specific/vendor dependent, I would be primarily interested in HTC phones.

Answer (score 2):

I've had success using [mad mpeg decoder](http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/) and [fmod 3](http://www.fmod.org/index.php/download)
You'll need to do p/invoke to use it from .NET though.

There's a support forums for fmod 3 @ http://www.fmod.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=2.
You can also check out the code project article [Simple MP3 Player for Pocket PC using FMOD](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/simple_mp3_player_for_ppc.aspx)